# Fixing a cycling image background behind main div and floating menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image

I am curious how I would go about keeping a cycling image background still behind the main content while one scrolls the page. Here is a link to the project itself. Feel free to use any of the code you want on your project, including the fixed header menu. I've been working on this template for a while, now.

http://www.famebyname.us/neep.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using **`background-attachment: fixed`**.

Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmLsa7gk/) or the following snippet for a visual example.

**Snippet:**

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://support.files.wordpress.com/2009/07/pigeony.jpg?w=688);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

#a1 {
  background-color: black;
}

#a2 {
  background-color: green;
}

#a3 {
  background-color: red;
}

#a4 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#a5 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#a6 {
  background-color: violet;
}

#a7 {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id = "a1"></div>
<div id = "a2"></div>
<div id = "a3"></div>
<div id = "a4"></div>
<div id = "a5"></div>
<div id = "a6"></div>
<div id = "a7"></div>
```